# Multiple conditions in an SQL Delete statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am using java in combination with mysql for a web application. I wanted to ask if this statement would work fine.

```
String delete="DELETE FROM `eoms`.`order` WHERE (`employeeID` = '"+eID+"', orderTime = '"+mealName+"', orderDate = '"+curDate+"');";
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with constants!

Comment: Don't concatenate input into SQL strings. Learn how to use a PreparedStatement

Comment: One way to determine whether a MySQL DELETE statement "will work" is to write it first as a `SELECT` statement... `SELECT o.* FROM eoms.order o WHERE ( o.emplyeeid = ? AND o.ordertime = ? AND o.orderdate = ? )`  and then verify that the select statement "works" and returns the rows that we want to remove. Then we can replace `SELECT` keyword with `DELETE` keyword ... (and echoing previous recommendations, use prepared statements with bind placeholders "little bobby tables" https://xkcd.com/327/ )

Comment: @Gordon, what kind of problem can occur if I don't use `PreparedStatement`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your delete query should work, but you should use a prepared statement:

```
String delete = "DELETE FROM `eoms`.`order` WHERE employeeID = ? OR orderTime = ? OR orderDate = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(delete);
ps.setInt(1, eID);
ps.setTime(2, orderTime);
ps.setDate(3, curDate);
int row = ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(row + " rows were deleted.");
```

Side notes: Please avoid naming your tables (and other database objects) using reserved SQL keywords such as `order`.  You will forever have to escape your `order` table in backticks.  Also, it appears that you are storing the order time and date in separate columns.  This probably isn't best practice, and you should consider just using a single datetime column for the order.  Finally, perhaps you intended for all three restrictions in the `WHERE` clause to apply simultaneously.  If so, then just swap `OR` with `AND`.

Comment: _"your delete query should work"_, not with the where clause as shown in the question.

Comment: @Mark Yes, you're right...I guess I subconsciously filtered off the commas.

Answer (score 4):

You should combine conditions with `and` operator

```
String delete="DELETE FROM `eoms`.`order` WHERE (`employeeID` = '"+eID+"' and orderTime = '"+mealName+"' and orderDate = '"+curDate+"')";
```

As recommended, use prepare statement for your parameter to avoid a SQL injection

```
  String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM `eoms`.`order` WHERE employeeID =? and orderTime =? and orderDate=? ";
  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
  preparedStmt.setInt(1, eID);
  preparedStmt.setInt(2, mealName);
  preparedStmt.setInt(3, curDate);   

  preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

  conn.close();
```